# Retrieving auto configuration with programmatic beans registration

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, dependency-injection

I'm looking for a way to retrieve auto configuration (values) to use them inside of beans registration. I don't use the component scan feature and still want to make use of constructor injection. So far I haven't found any way to do that and there's no documentation which shows what has to be done.

In the following example I want to initialize the `PubSubTemplate` (spring gcp). The ctor accepts two parameters a `PublisherFactory` and a `SubscriberFactory`. They themselves need a `GcpProjectIdProvider`.
The auto configuration in spring has the value for the latter. As stated before I couldn't find a way to retrieve that value.

```
beans {

    bean<GcpProjectIdProvider> {
        DefaultGcpProjectIdProvider()
    }
    bean<PublisherFactory>("publisher") {
        DefaultPublisherFactory(ref())
    }
    bean<SubscriberFactory>("subscriber") {
        DefaultSubscriberFactory(ref())
    }
    bean<PubSubOperations> {
        PubSubTemplate(ref<PublisherFactory>("publisher"), ref<SubscriberFactory>("subscriber"))
    }

}
```

Another service will use that template to do some operations:

```
open class FooBarServiceImpl(private val pubSubTemplate: PubSubTemplate) {

  fun doSomething() {
    pubSubTemplate.subscribe(...) { ... }
  }

}
```

The issue with the code I showed is that the `GcpProjectIdProvider` doesn't contain the correct information. This information is available from auto configuration.

Comment: Do you have an exception or something?

Comment: It's not really an exception. In my cause as with GCP it just says that it can't get the default project ID.